# SocketException: Failed host lookup: ‘....co’ (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)

Tags: dart, flutter

On app launch I get this error: SocketException: Failed host lookup: ‘....co’ (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)

Also my flutter docotor -v output is:

```
Heyabs-MacBook-Pro:flutterLoginApp-master4OK heyab$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /Users/heyab/flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (3 months ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/heyab/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.31.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.23.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Heyab's iPhone • 77afb908fc6c490d3fca62cdde9a74ab4e45b4f0 • ios • iOS 11.4.1

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was getting this error due to my device being offline. Once I set my device to be online, the error did not persist.

Comment: Do you mean physical device?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Make sure you are online whether it is mobile or emulator
> 2. Make sure you have given internet permission in your app's android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml